# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while using map for storing ordered data

Tags: c++, dictionary, type-conversion

found many posts with this error but none were of help..
i am calling a function to save read the books issued by a customer from a transactions map and then im reading the books price from a bookDetails map and saving the data to a customerBillList map with bill multiplied by -1 as key so that they are arranged in descending order( ascending order in negative)... but this function gives me the above error.. 
the function is

```
void getCustomerBills(map<string, string> transactions,map<string, string> bookDetails, map<double, string> &customerBillList)
 {
         map<string, string>::iterator transactionsIterator = transactions.begin();
         for (; transactionsIterator != transactions.end(); ++transactionsIterator)
         {
             double customerBill = 0;
             string customerID = transactionsIterator->first;
             string transactionsString = transactionsIterator->second;
             int length = transactionsString.length();
             for (int i = 0;i < length; ++i)
             {
             string book = "";
             while (transactionsString[i] != ',' and i < length)
             {
                 book = book + transactionsString[i];
                 ++i;
             }
             map<string, string>::iterator iteratorBookDetails = bookDetails.find(book);
             string bookCost = "";
             string bookDetailsString = iteratorBookDetails->second;
             for (int j = 0; j<bookDetailsString.length() and bookDetailsString[j] != ',' ; ++j)
             {
                 bookCost = bookCost + bookDetailsString[j];
             }
             customerBill = customerBill + atof(bookCost.c_str());
             }
             if (customerBillList.count((customerBill)* -1) == 0)
             customerBillList[(customerBill)* -1] = customerID;
             else 
             customerBillList[(customerBill)* -1] = customerBillList[(customerBill)* -1] + "," + customerID;
         }
 }
```

on doing some poking i found out that the value of double customerBill keeps on changing by itself each time the transaction iterator loops...

here are the maps just in case you need them
transactions:

```
Key    Value
    C12397 P342,P8,P563,P456
    C3452 P546,P8,P673,P675
    C1238 P1
    C12397 P8,P673,P4
```

bookDetails:

```
key Value
P342 500,Black Holes and Baby Universes
P8   90,Love in the time of Cholera
P675 23,Number Theory and Cryptography
P563 1000,Lord of the Rings ­ Box Set
P456 12,Da Vinci Code
P546 20,Linux Device Drivers
P673 45,The Great Indian Novel
P1   34,Predictably Irrational
P42  44,The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy
P99  99,Problems in Physic
```

does anybody see what the issue is here? any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Perhaps telling us what line of code the error occurs

Comment: the Segmentation fault does not give a line number and im using an online compiler so cant really use breakpoints..  if i knew that i would have probably solved the issue..  :(

Comment: That is why we have debuggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the result of:

```
map<string, string>::iterator iteratorBookDetails = bookDetails.find(book);
```

I can see in the example you gave that there's no record in `bookDetails` for P4. This means that the aforementioned line will return `bookDetails.end()`. Later, when you try to access the values pointed by `iteratorBookDetails`, you are sure to crash.

Comment: @Pundit BTW, what about a multimap?

Comment: @laune i dont really see how that will make a difference..  can you elaborate?

Comment: @Pundit The concatenation of customer ID values, separated by a comma, isn't good programming style unless you really need "C47,C567,C99" as a string. Possibly things would look even better if the other maps would have structured value parts rather than strings, and transactions as a multimap (or a map<String,vector<String>>) and Book should be class Book with members ID, title, price.

Comment: @laune yeah..  that was also an option but the comma separated list is how it is in the .list file and in case of transactions we need all or none of the transactions of the user in which case i think this is ok.. no?   neways thanks...  :)

Comment: @Pundit If you are bound to fumble with CSV strings you might find std::getline(istream& is, string& str, char delim) easier to use than the finicky iterations over a string, character by character.